# A Doob-Meyer decomposition related question

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

First I will state the question and then I will show my answer, which I obtained by imposing an additional condition on the processes involved. I would like to get some help on how to solve the original question without this additional condition.

So the question is as follows. Let $M$ and $N$ be continuous local martingales with $M_0 = N_0 = 0$. Suppose that $A$ with $A_0 = 0$ is a continuous adapted finite variation process and that the following holds.
$$(M_tN_t - A_t) \quad \text{is a local martingale.}$$
Prove that $A_t = [M,N]_t$ a.s.

My answer makes use of the additional condition that $M$ and $N$ are square-integrable. Then I write
$$M_tN_t - A_t = M_tN_t - [M,N]_t + [M,N]_t - A_t$$
The square-integrability of $M$ and $N$ give $MN - [M,N]$ is a local martingale.
This implies $[M,N] - A$ is a local martingale. Furthermore, $[M,N]$ is a finite variation process, which combined with $A$ being of finite variation gives $[M,N] - A$ is of finite variation. Since all the processes involved are continuous, so is $[M,N] - A$. For a continuous local martingale $M$ of finite variation, we have $M_t = M_0$. This then implies $$[M,N]_t - A_t = [M,N]_0 - A_0 = 0 \qquad \square$$.

Is it possible to solve this question without the square-integrability condition? I don't want to rule out the possibility that the teacher forgot to mention this condition in the problem statement.

Edit 1: Apparently what I meant with $M$ and $N$ being square-integrable was that they were local $L^2$ martingales. This was my misunderstanding of the $L^2$-ness of local martingales.

Comment: You don't need the condition of square integrability. Theorem 27, ch II of Protter's Stochastic Integration and DE shows that if $(X)$ is a local martingale then $(X^2- \langle X\rangle)$ is also a local martingale.

Comment: @user3371583 Thanks for your answer. So then I can keep my proof the way it is but I need to show that $MN - [M,N]$ is local martingale under the assumptions in the original question?

Comment: It suffices to prove the statement for a local martingale $X$ (which you can by applying Ito's formula to $x\mapsto x^2$). After you apply that result to the local martingale $(M-N)$ to show that it works also for $MN$. Imposing square integrability is too strong. You've turned the local martingale into a true martingale.

Comment: @user3371583 But then I get something like $X^2_t - [X]_t = 2\int_0^tX_s\ dX_s$. The stochastic integral on the rhs must then be a local martingale for your statement to hold and for this stochastic integral to be well-defined the process $X$ must be $L^2$. So I am stuck in some kind of tautology.

Comment: Have you studied the stochastic integral w.r.t a local martingale? It's just a local martingale. No assumptions of *global* square integrability are needed. Only **local** square integrability (which is given to you by the local martingale definition).

Comment: Well the textbook is right in front of me. I am looking at the chapter semimartingale integrator. It says "to define the stochastic integral, we need $M$ to be a local $L^2$-martingale. Here $M$ is the local martingale component of the semimartingale. But then when I look back at the chapter on the local martingale integrator, it is required that the stopped process $X^{\tau_k}$ is a square-integrable martingale where $\tau_k$ is the localizing sequence for the integrand-integrator pair.  Also, local square integrability is not part of the definition of local martingales in our textbook.

Comment: Yes. $M$ is a local $L^2$ martingale, that means that $M^{\tau_k}$ is an $L^2$ martingale. It doesn't mean that $M$ is an $L^2$ local martingale which would mean something else. By local square integrability, I mean that the localised local martingale is an $L^2$-martingale. Of course you dont need to mention "local $L^2$ martingale" everytime cuz a localised local martigale is bounded martingale, therefore $L^\infty$, therefore $L^2$. You quickly forget saying $L^2$ and just say local martingale.